# Grepping out data from a returned wget

Tags: json, bash, parsing, grep

I am writing a bash script to use with badips.com

This command:

```
wget https://www.badips.com/get/key -qO -
```

Will return something like this:

```
{"err":"","suc":"new key 5f72253b673eb49fc64dd34439531b5cca05327f has been set.","key":"5f72253b673eb49fc64dd34439531b5cca05327f"}
```

Or like this:

```
{"err":"","suc":"Your Key was already present! To overwrite, see http:\/\/www.badips.com\/apidoc.","key":"5f72253b673eb49fc64dd34439531b5cca05327f"}
```

I need to parse the key value out (`5f72253b673eb49fc64dd34439531b5cca05327f`) into a variable in the script. I would prefer to use `grep` to do it but can't get it right.

Comment: You should use the jq tool: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: It's obviously json data, why not use a json parser? `python -m json` springs to mind.

Comment: It looks like it should be a simple use of `grep -o REGEXP`, and the regexp should just match the string after `"key":"`.. What problem are you having? Please show what you tried.

Comment: If you *have* to use `grep`, look at the `-o` option, which prints *only* the matched part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below grep command,

```
grep -oP '"key":"\K[^"]*(?=")' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of parsing with some `grep`, you have the perfect tool for this: [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

See:

```
jq '.key' file
```

or

```
.... your_commands .... | jq '.key'
```

will return

```
"5f72253b673eb49fc64dd34439531b5cca05327f"
```

---

See another example, for example to get the `suc` attribute:

```
$ cat a
{"err":"","suc":"new key 5f72253b673eb49fc64dd34439531b5cca05327f has been set.","key":"5f72253b673eb49fc64dd34439531b5cca05327f"}
{"err":"","suc":"Your Key was already present! To overwrite, see http:\/\/www.badips.com\/apidoc.","key":"5f72253b673eb49fc64dd34439531b5cca05327f"}
$ jq '.suc' a
"new key 5f72253b673eb49fc64dd34439531b5cca05327f has been set."
"Your Key was already present! To overwrite, see http://www.badips.com/apidoc."
```

Comment: This will work, but I didn't want to require people to have jq installed.

Comment: It is not a good practise to use regex when working with JSON, like you wouldn't with XML. Instead, use the tools given for this. Also, install `jq` is just a command.

Comment: @fedorqui it's far easier to parse json than it is to parse xml, but i agree it's also better to use a tool that is made for the job.

Comment: +1 for this nice new tool in my toolbox. Using Node.js will be overkill

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
wget https://www.badips.com/get/key -qO - |
    perl -MJSON -MFile::Slurp=slurp -le '
        my $s = slurp "/dev/stdin";
        my $d = JSON->new->decode($s);
        print $d->{key}
'
```

Not as strong as precedent one, but that don't require to install new modules, a stock `perl` can do it :

```
     wget https://www.badips.com/get/key -qO - | 
         perl -lne 'print $& if /"key":"\K[[:xdigit:]]+/'
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` keeps it simple

```
wget ... - | awk -F:  '{split($NF,k,"\"");print k[2]}'
```

1. the field separator is `:`;
2. the key is always in the last field, in `awk` this field is accessed using `$NF` (Number of Fields);
3. the `split` function splits `$NF` and puts the pieces in array `k`, according to separator `"\""` that is just a single double quote character;
4. the second field of the `k` array is what you want.